# PIE with added on hover border

Tags: html, css, css3pie

There is simple example: http://fsou1.ru/files/verstka_examples/14/index2.html

I use PIE.js for attaching border-radius in IE, but when i add 'border: 30px solid black' on hover event, PIE.js doesn't want to round this added border!

Is there any solution to round added border on hover event too?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a `span{ border: 30px solid transparent }` and just do `span:hover{ border-color: #000 }`. That should solve it. The problem is that by adding that border only on hover, you're basically asking PIE to redraw the element, and seeing as it's basically just a shiv, it can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not totally lost this is the problem that PIE runs at the rendering of the page to add elements to the DOM, so it can fake the look of border radius.

PIE don't listen to any events by default (and I'm not sure it can be done).